# What does "bismillah" mean in the Bohemian Rhapsody?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, queen

According to Google, Bismillah means:

> in the name of God (an invocation used by Muslims at the beginning of
>   an undertaking).

But, is that the same context in which it is used? If not, then what does it mean in context of the song?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There was apparently an official explanation given for the use of the word:

> In 2004, Queen's Greatest Hits became the first rock album allowed in
>   Iran. The cassette came with an explanatory leaflet which insisted the
>   hero "killed a man" by accident, then sold his soul to the devil. On
>   the night before his execution he calls God in Arabic - "Bismillah" -
>   and so regains his soul from Satan.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-13761091

Of course given the market in which the product was released, this could be seen as a non-definitive interpretation of the reason for the use of the word. However, it does at least confirm that the word is indeed *Bismillah* and used in its normal meaning.